# BufferedReader issue: String and Numeric values from a .txt are being retrieved as null and zeros

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have tried to get string and numeric values from a text file using BufferedReader. Apparently, it is recognizing the number of records (lines) of the text file, but the values are not being retrieved as they are. String ones are being placed as "null" and double as zeros. I am kind of new in Java and I would like to know the possible reason of this output and also how could I solve it.

[image]

I tried to adapt the results to an arraylist as part of a table visualization, however after some tries it was not possible solve the problem:

```
private ArrayList<ListClasses> seeListe() {
    ArrayList<ListClasses> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    File file = new File("C:/file/to/path/file.txt");
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {               
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = breader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            list.add(new ListClasses());
            line = breader.readLine();
        }           
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + file.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read file: " + file.toString());
    }
    finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to close file: " + file.toString());
        }
        catch(NullPointerException ex) {
        }
    }
    
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You never do anything with the value assigned to `line`. Currently, you read a line, assign it to `line`, and then do nothing with it at all. You don't show the code of `ListClasses`, but you probably need to populate it somehow. As an aside, never **ever** catch `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I'm guessing that the empty data is what it looks like when you create an instance of `ListClasses` using the empty ctor and none of its members gets populated. Certainly that is not in any way interacting with what you're reading and I'm guessing it should, e.g. `list.add(new ListClasses(line));`

Answer (score 0):

The records in you file should really represent *one* object so your class name shouldn't be a plural, but if your ctor is right, you can just do:

```
List<ListClasses> data = Files.lines(Paths.get(pathToDataFile)).map(ListClasses::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```